# Why the ShowWindow is not hiding the window handle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of form1 i did:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hwnd, bool enable);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width,
        int height, bool redraw);
```

Then the SW_SHOW

```
int SW_SHOW = 5;
```

Then in the a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] cmdTextParts = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
            foreach (string item in cmdTextParts)
            {
                cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("GrAD"))
                    {
                        names.Add(process.ProcessName + " " + process.Id + " " + process.MainWindowTitle);
                        if (process.MainWindowTitle == "GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2"))
                        {
                            IntPtr HWND = process.MainWindowHandle;
                            ShowWindow(HWND, SW_SHOW);
                            EnableWindow(HWND, true);
                            MoveWindow(HWND, 0, 0, 640, 480, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to change the SW_SHOW it was in original 5 tried 4 and 3 but it didn't hide it. Another problem is the `MoveWindow(HWND, 0, 0, 640, 480, true);`
It's not changing the window size. Tried 100, 100 and even 10, 10

Also it didn't change the window location tried instead 0, 0 to make 500, 500 but it didn't change.

Comment: Try `0`, the value of `SW_HIDE`. Did you try to debug? Does it break inside the most inner `if`?

Comment: Yacoub it's working i had to add a Sleep(10000) before since this window show too fast. Is there any other way to wait for the window and not to show it or capture it on the way and not show it ? I want that i will not need to wait for the window 5-10 seconds but already make it not to be shown. I know the window handle: 1575576 but the handle number change each time i'm running the program over again. Maybe if i change the Sleep from 10000 to only one millisecond Sleep(1) it will be fast enough so i will not see the window at all ?

Comment: Ok what i need is to make somehow that the window will start minimized to the TaskBar or to the tray icon. Is there any way to do it ? Not to show the window for a second and at all. Also not to hide it or close it like i'm doing now. But to start it as minimized.